# Windows 2003 Boot Password

Tags: windows-server-2003, password, boot

I inherited a Win2003 Dell Poweredge server. When booting there comes up a box asking for a password to make the server available. It is not an BIOS password nor the windows session login box. it is just before the windows session login.

I cannot figure out how to disable this. Do you have any hint ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Account Database encryption password.

By default, the Account Database is encrypted using a key stored in registry, but the administrator can choose to store it in a floppy disk, or use a password instead.

If you know the password, run `syskey`, click "Update" and choose "Store Startup Key Locally" to restore the normal behavior.

(The encryption is always enabled and you cannot disable it completely; the "Encryption disabled" option is there since Windows NT 4.0.)

If you don't know the password, reinstalling is the only option [that I know of] - after, of course, backing up all data with a LiveCD.